# Specify how text wraps around an image in Markdown

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Is there any way of telling Markdown how to wrap text around an image, or are all images considered blocks?

I can't find anything in the Markdown documentation that allows for this, but is this at least possible in [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In vanilla markdown, no, it provides no support for that kind of styling. Extensions may support on other implementations, but that is rather engine specific. in particular you could do it via pandoc via a filter, although they are a little tricky to get going on writing them - I'd recommend looking at the python wrapper for them ([here](https://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters)).

Otherwise, it's export to html/tex and style by hand afterwards I'm afraid. Markdown is deliberately fairly simple.